# Не выводится рисунок

Tags: php

```
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'image');
?>
<image src="image/risunok.png">
```

Comment: Значит проблема с путями.
Проверяйте выводится ли рисунок по прямой ссылке.

Comment: Что делает строчка   

    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'image');
?

Comment: <img src="image/risunok.png"/> попробуй так

Answer (score 1):

Блин чтобы ответить на вопрос автора, нужно сначала понять ЗАЧЕМ!
Ну ладно... считаем, что поняли...

```
<?php
    // DOCUMENT_ROOT равен '/дисковый/путь/к/корню/вашего/веб-пространства'
    // image видимо название папки

    // Скорее всего, здесь надо получить путь к файлу
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'image');
?>
<img src="image/risunok.png" />
<img src="http://www.santarosa.edu/~dpearson/2010fall/cis5852/lessons/07/images/doc_root.jpg" />
```

Проверьте, будет ли хоть что-нибудь отображаться...